# Switching Solr cores when adding documents

Tags: solr, solr4

I use multiple cores with Solr and when it comes to adding the document I use the approach to look at the object and compose the URL to match the core as follows:

```
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = getASolrInputDocumentFromSomewhere();
Object bean = request.getBean();
String core;

if (bean instanceof EntityOne)
  core = "coreone";
else if (bean instanceof EntityTwo)
  core = "coretwo";
[...]

SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/" + core);

server.add(solrDoc);
server.commit();
```

(This is *not* the code I actually use, It's shortened and squeezed to only provide the idea.)

This works but is it a correct approach or are there any other possibilities provided which allow to set the core or even a way that Solr auto-detects the core needed according to the document structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data Solr offers a `MulticoreSolrServerFactory` which can handle and create `SolrServer` instances. It basically works like this.

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core1")
private static class Bean1 {

  //..

}

factroy = new MulticoreSolrServerFactory(new HttpSolrServer("http://127.0.0.1:8983"));

SolrServer solrServer = factory.getSolrServer(Bean1.class);
```

Comment: Looks more elegant. I'll give it a try!